# How to get url text out of field with HYPERLINK in it

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with hyperlinks formula in it, for example:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://example.com", "Link")
```

I want to get additional column, where only urls (as a text) from the first column will be present, that is, in this example:

```
http://example.com
```

Is there a function that allows extraction of an url from HYPERLINK? I was thinking also about getting formula text from the first column and cutting it with SPLIT/SUBSTITUTE in the final one, but I'm not sure if I can get one field code into another field.

Answer (score 6):

Try this formulas

```
A2=index(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=HYPERLINK(""",""),""","""),1,1)
```

example

```
A1=HYPERLINK("http://example.com", "Link")
```

result is

```
A2=http://example.com
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just created this script and it worked

```
function URL(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
  
  try {
    var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  return range;


}
```

Comment: This script works without the quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using Apps Script to create a custom function. Try this:

1. Open your Google Sheet.
2. In the menu bar, open **Tools > Script editor...**
3. In **Code.gs**, paste the following and save:

   ```
   function EXTRACT_URL(input) {

     var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input);
     var re = /^.+?\(\"(.+?)\",.+?$/;
     if (input.indexOf(':') != -1) {
       var formulas = range.getFormulas();
       for (var i in formulas) {
         for (var j in formulas[i]) {
           formulas[i][j] = formulas[i][j].replace(re, "$1");
         }
       }
       return formulas;
     } else {
       return range.getFormula().replace(re, "$1");
     }

   }
   ```

This creates a custom function. In your Google Sheet, you can use this function as you would use any other function; however, there's one caveat, which is that you'll have to put the cell in quotes, e.g.:

```
=EXTRACT_URL("A1")
```

To make the quotes thing less of a hassle, the above script supports ranges as well:

```
=EXTRACT_URL("A1:B10")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: wasn't able to get this to work. the text had the hyperlink in my case

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to copy the column containing the formulae (assuming you would like to retain them) and remove the 'excess'. The removal can be achieved with Edit > Find and Replace... with *Replace with* left blank in each case:

**The part to the left:**

*Find* `=HYPERLINK("` and check *Also search within formulae*

(If you want to break the link, put `'` in *Replace with *.)

**The part to the right:**

*Find* `".+` and check *Search using regular expressions* and *Also search within  formulae*.

Comment: My version of google sheets doesn't have the option "Also search within formulae" in Find and Replace. Trying to replace text in column with HYPERLINKs results in "Note: Text can't be replaced in formula cells."

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros) and a combination of Macros, Menus, and Custom Functions to extract the value of the hyperlink out of the cell's formula.

Here's how it would work:

1. Open the Google Sheets document
2. Go to Tools > Script Editor...
   *A new browser window or tab will open*
3. Highlight and delete all of the code in `Code.gs`
4. Replace everything in `Code.gs` with the contents from [this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yMCyRyq0), taken from [this Google Docs Help Forum
   topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ymxKs_QVEbs)
5. Save the changes by going to File > Save
6. Run this new script by clicking on Run > onOpen
7. When prompted, authorize the script
8. Go back to your Google Sheets document
   *You'll see a new menu item has been created after Help, named "Extract"*
9. Select the cell(s), row(s) or column(s) in your spreadsheet that contain the `=HYPERLINK` functions
10. Click on `Extract -> Replace formulas with Text strings` to initiate the script

The macro will recursively extract out the URL of the hyperlink function, leaving you with just the value.

Note: Always make a backup of your work before making any changes.

I would recommend performing this task on a duplicate spreadsheet or at a minimum a copy of the original cells in case anything should go wrong of if you wish to retain the original cell's content or formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text of the hyperlink formula cell using FORMULATEXT, then extract the URL using a regular expression.

`=REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1), "^=HYPERLINK(""([^""]+)")`