# How to extract url from Google Sheet Cell with anchor text hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have copied a list of links from the web to a google spreadsheet.

Now there is a list of hyperlinked text in each cell.

I want to put the url underneath the anchor text into a new cell.

However, the only methods discussed online refer to how to get a url from a cell that is using the HYPERLINK() function.  My cells are not using such a function, they are simply copied and pasted from a website, but still retain their anchor text and hyperlink. Other options use Macros/VBA, which I cannot use/have access to.

How can I replace these anchor text in a Google Sheets cell with the links they represent or copy them into a new cell?

Comment: Now you can get ancor link from cell by custom function from this answer https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89564/86039 I test it and it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract URL from Link in Google Sheets using a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230764/how-to-extract-url-from-link-in-google-sheets-using-a-formula)

Comment: Try https://extract-urls.contributor.pw/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only a partial answer, but I spent an embarrassing amount of time recently trying to extract links from a spreadsheet that were done the way you describe.

The only way I was able to finally do it was to export the sheet as HTML, and use regex to find the `href`s and extract them.

Full discloser, my wife came up with this in about 10 minutes, meanwhile I wasted many hours playing with the Google Sheets API, Open Office, Excel, and various xlsx parsing libraries for Go.

Anyway - if you just need to extract the links, it's not impossible, but it's not very practical either.

Comment: Once you export as HTML, you can open the file in a browser, and then use Javascript (in the console) to get the urls out. @evillemez , you may want to include a js snippet in your answer that extracts the links, like:: let links = document.querySelectorAll('a'); for (let link of links) { link.innerHTML = link.href; }

Comment: I'm back again! Thanks for your answer @evillemez