# How do you extract urls from a column of cells containing linked text with numeric values in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

Edit/Update: This question is helpful for the specific use case where you are trying to extract urls from cells containing **numeric** values with linked URLs.

I have a spreadsheet with a column of cells copied from a website containing text with linked urls (i.e. the urls are not stored within a hyperlink formula). Here is a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eWpvG544dRTcYObu7q4_ZZQV1cXcdo0_jS75zNVaz5M/edit?usp=sharing). I would like to extract the urls from the linked text (column A) into a new column in the spreadsheet.

Last year (2020) I found the custom function javascript code shared in the comments of [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230764/how-to-extract-url-from-link-in-google-sheets-using-a-formula) which worked well. However when I tried this with a new spreadsheet yesterday, this code was no longer working -- instead of returning the url, it returns nothing. There is no error message, it just returns an empty value.

Other things I've tried:
I was able to successfully retrieve the url in some cases by using this other javascript function:

```js
function GETLINK(input) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
}
```

But it only worked correctly on cells where the text was not formatted as a number AND it requires entering the input as either a firm cell reference by putting it in quotes i.e. =getlink("A2") or by spelling out the address, i.e. =getlink(ADDRESS(ROW(A2), COLUMN(A2)))

I would like to figure out what has broken with the original code, which does not require these additional workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue), `getRichTextValue()` will return `null` if the value of the cell is not formatted as text. Most of the codes on the reference question use this method, so it returns error once `getLinkUrl()` is called. Thus the only workaround for this is to force text formatting by putting single quote before the cell value:

[image]

This should also work with `linkURL()`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation and workarounds, Carlos M. I also found that highlighting the column of numbers with linked urls and selecting Format > Number > Plain text  was a good way of converting a batch of these numeric values to text.