# Concatenate two cells and hyperlink to embedded a link from of of the concatenated cells

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I have 2 cells with data inside of them

Cell A1
Contains text
"Search: "

Cell B1
Contains a hyperlink
https://www.google.com
Display Text
"Google"

I want C1 to say "Search : Google" hyperlinked so that when I click on it, it takes me to Google.

The formulas I tried

```
=HYPERLINK(B1, CONCATENATE(A1, ":", B1, "(", C1, ")"))

=CONCATENATE(A1, ":", HYPERLINK(B1, CONCATENATE(B1, "(", C1, ")")))
```

Both formulas return in Cell C1
"Search : Google"

But the hyperlink tends to grab the display text which is Google instead of https://www.google.com

Comment: In cell `B1` is url embedded in the style of using a formula like `=hyperlink("http://www.google.com/","Google")` OR its done by `Insert link`  functionality?!

Comment: I added the link to B1 then right clicked and clicked on edit hyperlink. I added a display text after that. Originally doing hyperlink(B1,"") should grab the link only but that doesn't even do that @rockinfreakshow

Comment: In that case you could look into the answer mentioned in this Q&A thread here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67206954/5479575)