# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFormula' of null (line 3, file "Code") - URL FORMULA

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

I am trying to add a custom formula via Google Script Editor and I keep getting the error message in the title. Below is the string.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFormula' of null (line 3, file "Code") - URL FORMULA**

```
function linkURL(reference) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula()
var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
try {
  var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
}
catch(e) {
throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
}
var formulas = range.getFormulas();
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
  var row = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
    var url = formulas[i][j].match(/=hyperlink\("([^"]+)"/i);
  row.push(url ? url[1] : '');
}
output.push(row);
}
return output
```

}

Comment: [Guidelines for Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions).  Perhaps that get is not available to custom functions.

Comment: It is, but it is resulting in an error. Not sure where to look.

Comment: How do you know it is?

Comment: Here is where I got the original script from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474308/how-to-get-url-text-out-of-field-with-hyperlink-in-it/37930113 Also - appreciate the help!

Comment: That wasn't an accepted answer and a fairly new user so perhaps they were wrong. The questioner was not able to get it to work.

Comment: Ah got it - I am new as well. Do you have any advice as to where I can find a solution to extract a link from hyperlinked text in a cell in Google Docs?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230764/how-to-extract-url-from-link-in-google-sheets-using-a-formula

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
function getLink() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  let v=sh.getRange('You specify range').getFormula();
  v=v.match(/([^"]+)/g);
  Logger.log(v[1]);
}
```

This may not work in the older and slower version of Apps Script.  Try using the ES6 version by enabling V8